# Regression for a model of form $y=ax^k$?

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

I have a dataset which is statistics from a web discussion forum. I'm looking at the distribution of the number of replies a topic is expected to have. In particular, I've created a dataset which has a list of topic reply counts, and then the count of topics which have that number of replies.

```
"num_replies","count"
0,627568
1,156371
2,151670
3,79094
4,59473
5,39895
6,30947
7,23329
8,18726
```

If I plot the dataset on a log-log plot, I get what is basically a straight line:

[image: Data plotted on log-log scale]

(This is a [Zipfian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)). Wikipedia tells me that straight lines on log-log plots imply a function that can be modelled by a monomial of the form $y = ax^k$. And in fact I've eyeballed such a function:

```
lines(data$num_replies, 480000 * data$num_replies ^ -1.62, col="green")
```

[image: Eyeballed model]

My eyeballs obviously aren't as accurate as R. So how can I get R to fit the parameters of this model for me more accurately? I tried polynomial regression, but I don't think that R tries to fit the exponent as a parameter - what is the proper name for the model I want?

Edit: Thanks for the answers everyone. As suggested, I've now fit a linear model against the logs of the input data, using this recipe:

```
data <- read.csv(file="result.txt")

# Avoid taking the log of zero:
data$num_replies = data$num_replies + 1

plot(data$num_replies, data$count, log="xy", cex=0.8)

# Fit just the first 100 points in the series:
model <- lm(log(data$count[1:100]) ~ log(data$num_replies[1:100]))

points(data$num_replies, round(exp(coef(model)[1] + coef(model)[2] * log(data$num_replies))), 
       col="red")
```

The result is this, showing the model in red:

[image: Fitted model]

That looks like a good approximation for my purposes.

If I then use this Zipfian model (alpha = 1.703164) along with a random number generator to generate the same total number of topics (1400930) as the original measured dataset contained (using [this C code I found on the web](http://coderepos.org/share/browser/lang/cplusplus/boost-supplement/trunk/boost_supplement/random/zipf_distribution.hpp)), the result looks like:

[image: Random number generated results]

Measured points are in black, randomly generated ones according to the model are in red.

I think this shows that the simple variance created by randomly generating these 1400930 points is a good explanation for the shape of the original graph.

If you're interested in playing with the raw data yourself, I have [posted it here](http://s3.chickensmoothie.com/misc/research/topic_reply_counts_for_1400930_forum_topics.txt.zip).

Comment: Why not just take logs of both counts & num_replies, & fit a standard linear model to them?

Comment: What's that huge spike in counts just below 10000 replies?

Comment: Neither counts nor log-counts have constant variance (for counts, variance will increase with mean, for log-counts it will generally decrease with mean). Given both variables are counts and many counts are quite small, I'd lean toward a Poisson, quasi-Poisson, or negative binomial GLM, perhaps with a log-link. If you must use ordinary regression, at least deal with the variance issue. Another alternative is to do an Anscombe or Freeman-Tukey transform of the counts and fit a nonlinear least squares model.

Comment: That interesting spike is due to a human-enforced "maximum topic length" in several forums.

Comment: Power functions don't usually include the case where one variable is zero. (You fudged that by adding 1.) Let's put it diplomatically and call your case something different, perhaps a shifted power function. I note that the zeros were explicit in your listing, but everyone looked at the graph.

Comment: Fudge is delicious :) More prosaically, there's no difference between (num_replies + 1) and (num_posts_in_topic).

Comment: Good answer. Undo therefore the comment on shifted power function.

Comment: I faced a similar situation and solved it slightly differently. Let me know your thoughts on this approach. The value of k and a need to be determined ( if polynomial, k and a would be vectors). I vary k between -1 and 1 and find the value of k for which pow(x,k) correlates best with y using a macro. I take the top three k which help x correlate with y. I start regressing y versus pow(x,k) and vary k between the top values in priority and observe model fitment, error structure to decide. Slightly approximate approach, but has worked well in polynomial situations. Because it is a sas macro and

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question. Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers. If you have your own question, click the `ASK QUESTION` at the top & ask it there; then we can help you properly. Since you are relatively new here, you may want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which has information for new users.

Comment: You cannot simply fit linearly the log data. Errors will not be gaussian distributed and the outcome will simply wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your example is a very good one because it clearly points up recurrent issues with such data.

Two common names are power function and power law. In biology, and some other fields, people often talk of allometry, especially whenever you are relating size measurements. In physics, and some other fields, people talk of scaling laws.

I would not regard monomial as a good term here, as I associate that with integer powers. For the same reason this is not best regarded as a special case of a polynomial.

Problems of fitting a power law to the tail of a distribution morph into problems of fitting a power law to the relationship between two different variables.

The easiest way to fit a power law is take logarithms of both variables and then fit a straight line using regression. There are many objections to this whenever both variables are subject to error, as is common. The example here is a case in point as both variables (and neither) might be regarded as response (dependent variable). That argument leads to a more symmetric method of fitting.

In addition, there is always the question of assumptions about error structure. 
Again, the example here is a case in point as errors are clearly heteroscedastic. That suggests something more like weighted least-squares.

One excellent review is http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16573844

Yet another problem is that people often identify power laws only over some range of their data. The questions then become scientific as well as statistical, going all the way down to whether identifying power laws is just wishful thinking or a fashionable amateur pastime. Much of the discussion arises under the headings of fractal and scale-free behaviour, with associated discussion ranging from physics to metaphysics. In your specific example, a little curvature seems evident.

Enthusiasts for power laws are not always matched by sceptics, because the enthusiasts publish more than the sceptics. I'd suggest that a scatter plot on logarithmic scales, although a natural and excellent plot that is essential, should be accompanied by residual plots of some kind to check for departures from power function form.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I wasn't able to find anything like this where people were discussing "polynomial regression". I've updated my question with the results from fitting that model!

Comment: If you're looking for a slightly more rigorous approach to the fitting of power laws, and significance tests for the fitted model, you probably want this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062 and the accompanying code: http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/

Comment: The paper cited above is for distributions that are power laws, not relationships between variables that are power laws. The title of this question fits the latter better; the example of this question fits the former better.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that a power is a good model to fit, then you can use `log(y) ~ log(x)` as your model, and fit a linear regression using `lm()`:

Try this:

```
# Generate some data
set.seed(42)

x <- seq(1, 10, 1)

a = 10
b = 2
scatt <- rnorm(10, sd = 0.2)


dat <- data.frame(
  x = x,
  y = a*x^(-b) + scatt
)
```

Fit a model:

```
# Fit a model
model <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x) + 1, data = dat) 
summary(model)

pred <- data.frame(
  x = dat$x,
  p = exp(predict(model, dat))
)
```

Now create a plot:

```
# Create a plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line(data = pred, aes(x=x, y=p), col = "red")
```

[image]