# Correcting for multiple tests over time

Tags: anova, t-test, bonferroni

I am measuring degradation of RNA over time with a control and a treatment. I have % RNA remaining (relative to time 0 for control and treatment) and 5 time points. I would like to test if the % remaining is different for control vs. treatment at each time point. I think that I need to correct for multiple comparisons, but unsure of exactly what test to use. I think I need to first do some kind of anova and then a post hoc test such as a t test with a Holm-Bonferroni correction, but this situation looked a bit different from most of the examples I saw where they are testing multiple comparisons within one time point.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't test for a statistical difference between the control and treatment time-courses at each time point. Are you thinking of hypotheses such as "there is a difference at time point 1 but not time point 3"? No. Look at the experiment as providing estimates of the degradation rate.

The first thing (*always*) in data analysis is to inspect the data graphically. My expectation is that RNA is pretty unstable and should degrade with an approximately exponential time-course, but you should know more about it and your data have the last say. Plot the amount remaining at the time points using a logarithmic amount scale. You might find a linear decline that is very easily characterised. You might even find that the difference is substantial enough that the graph is sufficiently persuasive without further analysis.

If you do want a more statistical analysis then I suggest fitting a model to the data to determine time-constants. The model to use depend on the form of the data and details of your analytic objectives, but I suggest you look at this question about [linear and non-linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61747/linear-vs-nonlinear-regression) as a starting point.